# Javascript file Type returning undefined

Tags: javascript

Looking for any ideas on why one specific user is failing some basic validation.  We have a file input that works for all other users, but is failing for one user who's receiving a file.Type of 'undefined'.  Simplified version of the code in question below:

```
<input type="file" id="file" />
<input type="button" value="Upload Attachment" onclick="startUpload()" id="uploadBtn" /> 


function startUpload(){

    var file = j$("#file")[0].files[0];

    if ( file === null || file === undefined ){
        // Handle Error
    } else {

        if (validFile(file)){
            processFile(file);
        }
    }
}

function validFile(file){

    console.log('file.Type = [' + file.Type + ']');

    if(file.type != "application/x-zip-compressed") {
        displayMessage("Error: Uploaded file must be a Zip file.",true);
    } 
}
```

The file the user is attempting to upload has been uploaded by other users/testers.  And this error persists regardless of the browser for him.  Anything I'm missing here?

Comment: Are you sure it's not `file.type`? Notice the casing.

Comment: @Li357, good catch. The console.log statement has the wrong case.  I'll correct and see if I'm able to get any better feedback on the MIME type being returned.  It's still unclear why the user would be failing that validation for a valid ZIP file, especially since others haven't encountered it with the same file.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to feedback by @Li357, the issue was that the script was only checking one of at least 5 MIME types used by ZIP archives:

- application/octet-stream
- multipart/x-zip
- application/zip
- application/zip-compressed
- application/x-zip-compressed

Updated validation to be more inclusive and is working as expected.